# is it possible to get the Path of InputStream as in eclipse debugger

Tags: java, inputstream

As in the picture attached, in eclipse debugger, I can see the path of InputStream (the red underline one), is it possible to get this "path" value in code?

[image]

Comment: Note that field is specific to `FileInputStream`, and may reference `null` according the source code. There's no guarantee `getResourceAsStream` will always return a `FileInputStream`. But that being said, you can get the value of the `path` field via reflection.

Comment: `this.getClass().getResource(resourcePathFileName)` returns `URL` to the file.

Comment: @saka yes, I use getResource(), then use the return URL getPath() method, and also use the returned URL openStream() to get the InputStream now